# Handling HTMLSelectElement Event

Tags: vb.net, mshtml

My code is:

```
Private htmlselReceteAlttur As mshtml.HTMLSelectElement


 htmlselReceteAlttur = htmlform.item("f:m8")

 AddHandler htmlselReceteAlttur.onclick, AddressOf htmlselReceteAlttur_onchange


 Private Function htmlselReceteAlttur_onchange(ByVal clicks As mshtml.HTMLSelectElementEvents_onclickEventHandler) As Boolean
```

bu vb says : "Error. Method 'Private Function htmlselReceteAlttur_onchange(clicks As mshtml.HTMLSelectElementEvents_onclickEventHandler) As Boolean' does not have a signature compatible with delegate 'Delegate Function HTMLSelectElementEvents_onclickEventHandler() As Boolean'

what will i use for handling? i cannot not use "Private **Withevents** htmlselReceteAlttur As mshtml.HTMLSelectElement" becouse when i use withevent then the original javascript of the web stops.

Answer (score 0):

i got it. it must be:

```
Private Function htmlselReceteAlttur_onchange() As Boolean  'Handles htmlselReceteAlttur.onchange

End Function
```

but now again the javascript is closed and the onclick event of java is not working.